# Getting the checkbox item that was checked in MPF with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm

I'm currently trying to implement ctrl & shift selection capabilities on a long list of checkbox items. Right now, you can highlight/select items by clicking on the names in the list, and you can select groups by using ctrl or shift. However, this does not affect the checkboxes. I'd like to allow group checkbox toggling by checking/unchecking all selected items if an item in the selection has been checked/unchecked.

This means trying to retrieve the item that was checked/unchecked and comparing its IsSelected property.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190204/how-to-get-current-element-on-checkbox-in-wpf) is the closest thing I could find to the what I'm looking for.

This is the xaml I have right now:

```
<ListView Name="LeftListView"
          Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding CvsLeftListView}">

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Name="LeftListCheckBox"
                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CheckBoxChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                          Checked="LeftListCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="LeftListCheckBox_Unchecked"/>
                <TextBlock Name="LeftListName"
                           Text="{Binding Name}"
                           Margin="2,0,0,0"/>
            </VirtualizingStackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And part of the object class for reference:

```
public class MyObject : ObservableObject
{
    // Fields
    private string _id;
    private string _fullName;
    private string _name;

    private bool _isChecked;
    private bool _isVisible;
    private bool _isSelected;

    #region Constructors

    #region Properties
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up attaching an event listener to each object in the list. Whenever it was called, it would check to see if a) the checkbox was changed, b) the item was selected/highlighted, and c) the item is visible. If all of these were met, then it would change the checkbox for all other selected/highlighted items.

Here's the code in the ViewModel. I added this listener to the PropertyChanged event of the objects while in the constructor.

```
private void MyObject_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyObject modifiedItem = sender as MyObject;

    if (e.PropertyName == "IsChecked" && modifiedItem.IsVisible && modifiedItem.IsSelected)
    {
        if (this.LeftListViewDisplayList.Contains(modifiedItem))
        {
            this.PropagateCheck(this._cvsLeftListView, this.LeftListViewDisplayList, modifiedItem.IsChecked);
        }
    }
}

private void PropagateCheck(ICollectionView displayedCollection, ObservableCollection<MyObject> storedCollection, bool checkValue)
{
    List<int> _groupIndices = new List<int>(displayedCollection.Cast<MyObject>().Count());

    foreach (MyObject item in displayedCollection)
    {
        if (item.IsSelected)
        {
            _groupIndices.Add(storedCollection.IndexOf(item));
            item.IsSelected = false;
            item.IsChecked = checkValue;
        }
    }

    foreach (int i in _groupIndices)
    {
        storedCollection[i].IsSelected = true;
    }

    displayedCollection.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you well - you want to bind your CheckBoxes to ListBoxItem selection. So may be you just need the code below - changing CheckBox.IsChecked property binding to IsSelected one?

```
<CheckBox Name="LeftListCheckBox"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"... />
```

Comment: That's not quite what I was thinking. If the item gets unselected, wouldn't the checkbox also become unchecked? I'd like to allow the checkbox to remain checked independent of the item selection.